# When does the product of random matrices diverge?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, stability-theory

Suppose $A_i$ are IID samples of a random matrix-valued variable. I'm interested in determining whether the following infinite product is likely to diverge

$$A_1 A_2 A_3\cdots$$

Finding necessary+sufficient condition is [hard](https://perso.uclouvain.be/vincent.blondel/publications/97BT-jsr.pdf) (Theorem 2).

- There are cheap to compute sufficient conditions for the product to converge.
- Are there cheap to compute sufficient conditions for the product to diverge?

---

Of particular interest is case of $A_i=(I-x_i x_i^T)$ where $x_i$ are IID Gaussian. The case for isotropic Gaussian is solved [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443143/when-is-prod-i-0-infty-i-x-i-x-it-0-for-isotropic-gaussian-x-i), I'm looking for insight into non-isotropic case

Comment: One sufficient condition would be that the determinants are $>1$ ae. Possibly, that the expected value of the determinants are $>1$.

Comment: (in absolute value)

Comment: Makes sense although is quite restrictive. For instance matrices with isotropic zero centered gaussian entries would never satisfy this, no matter the variance

Comment: Agreed, it's a very strong condition. It's only a first stab.

Comment: For isotropic random variables, symmetry can be [used](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/443143/when-is-prod-i-0-infty-i-x-i-x-it-0-for-isotropic-gaussian-x-i), it would be nice to have simple divergence conditions for non-isotropic

Answer (score 1):

You generate a large enough sample of $x_i$ from a non-isotropic Gaussian distribution. Then for a sufficient number of samples n, generate matrices $A_1,A_2,\dots, A_n$. Then calculate the norm of product of these matrices. By Oseledets theorem, there is a $\lambda$ such that
\begin{equation}
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{1}{n} \log{(\lVert A_1 A_2 \cdots A_n \rVert)} = \lambda
\end{equation}
Where if $\lambda>0$, the product will almost surely diverge, while if $\lambda < 0$, the product will almost surely converge. For sufficient $n$, this can be estimated, which will provide reasonable parameters for the conditions you want.
I don't think this answers the question in the way you were hoping unfortunately.